# I want to copy a cell from one workbook to an active workbook using vba code

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Hungry4Gages()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dguitron\Documents\Belize and Sam Project\Class 1\run_10296500.xlsm")

Set y = ActiveWorkbook

'Now, copy what you want from x:

x.Sheets("dashboard").Range("D17").Copy

'Now, paste to y worksheet:

y.Sheets("Class1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial 

'Close x:

x.Close

End Sub
```

"dashboard " is the name of the sheet I am copying it from, and "Class1" is the sheet I am pasting on the active workbook.

I am getting the error "Subscript out of range" for the y.sheets(Class1)....

Comment: Do your `Set y` before you do your `Set x`.

Comment: @YowE3K - Totally missed that. You should make an answer!

Comment: @Jeeped - just finished (I posted the comment first so that people wouldn't go off on a tangent looking for other issues)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current code you are doing

```
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dguitron\Documents\Belize and Sam Project\Class 1\run_10296500.xlsm")

Set y = ActiveWorkbook
```

The `Workbooks.Open` statement opens a workbook **which then becomes the active workbook**.  Therefore both `x` and `y` are pointing to the same workbook.

So you need to switch the order around:

```
Set y = ActiveWorkbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dguitron\Documents\Belize and Sam Project\Class 1\run_10296500.xlsm")
```

---

As Jeeped pointed out, if your macros are in the workbook that you are setting `y` to, you could use `Set y = ThisWorkbook` and then the order would not be important, or you could just use `ThisWorkbook` everywhere where you otherwise would have used `y`.

(Personally, I would still set the reference to the "static", for want of a better word, workbooks first and then go and open other workbooks and set their object references - but that is just my personal preference based on the way I think about what I am doing.)

Comment: If the code was in the source workbook, it could be `Set y = ThisWorkbook`. In any event, good catch!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value a bit faster without opening the source Workbook with [external reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f):

```
[Class1!A1].Formula = "='C:\Users\dguitron\Documents\Belize and Sam Project\Class 1\[run_10296500.xlsm]dashboard'!D17"

[Class1!A1] = [Class1!A1].Value         ' optional to convert the formula to value
```